# python requests library AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'SESSION'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using MacOS
I installed requests library using pip3
And I get
" AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'SESSION' "

% python3 --version
Python 3.5.3

Reproduction Steps

```
# login.py
import requests

session = requests.SESSION()
python3 login.py
```

System Information

```
$ python -m requests.help

{
  "chardet": {
  "version": "3.0.4"
},
"cryptography": {
  "version": "2.1.4"
},
  "idna": {
  "version": "2.6"
},
"implementation": {
  "name": "CPython",
  "version": "3.5.3"
},
"platform": {
  "release": "17.2.0",
  "system": "Darwin"
},
"pyOpenSSL": {
  "openssl_version": "1010007f",
  "version": "17.5.0"
},
"requests": {
  "version": "2.18.4"
},
"system_ssl": {
  "version": "9081df"
},
"urllib3": {
  "version": "1.22"
},
"using_pyopenssl": true
```

}

Comment: Any idea or any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are spelling(making it all caps) it wrong

Try:

```
sess = requests.Session()
```

Comment: OMG. sorry... Ouch.